# overflow css working in ie but not working with firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, user-interface

overflow css working in Ie but not working with firefox

overflow:auto;

not working with firefox?

Comment: Posting some copy'n'paste'n'runnable code which demonstrates this would help us to help you in more detail.

Comment: it works perfectly to me... normally... you should provide more details, likely the quirks is not there.

Comment: Woah. Something works in IE and *not* Firefox. Welcome to Bizarro World.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox has excellent support for the `overflow` property (at least as specified in CSS 2.1, which includes the `auto` value).

The problem likely lies with some other part of your code (probably something to do with how you are trying to size the element, or possibly that your Doctype (or lack thereof) is triggering Quirks Mode).